# Docker Postgres images with data

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, images, postgresql

I have a bunch of DB backups used for QA and Integration Testing.
From time to time, the schema of these DBs gets updated.

I thought of Building Images for each DB instance and commit changes after the schema gets updated, and [this guide seems up to the job](https://sharmank.medium.com/build-postgres-docker-image-with-data-included-489bd58a1f9e).

But thinking about updating the Postgres instance, I'd like a setup where I've data images "bound" to Postgres images, so I can update PG or the Data independently.

Something similar to submodules in git.
Is there anything like that for docker?